# Responsive image inside vertical centered responsive container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive vertically centered lightbox, supporting different image sizes and controls relativ positioned to the image without the use of javascript.

I got it working in Safari, but unfortunately the image doesn't scale heightwise in Firefox and Chrome where it overflows its parent.

**Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sboesch/6yoLun5d/)**

**Here is my code:**

```css
.overlay {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    text-align:center;
    font-size:0;
}

.overlay:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    font-size:1rem;
    max-width:80%;
    max-height:80%;
}

.container img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

.container .caption {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.container .prev, .container .next {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.container .prev {
    left:0;
}

.container .next {
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">Some text...</div>
        <a class="prev" href="#">Previous</a>
        <a class="next" href="#">Next</a>
    <div>
</div>
```

Is it even possible to solve this problem without javascript?

Comment: Have you tried flexbox?

Comment: Not yet, but that could work. I'll try it, thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind Flexbox won't work on IE

Comment: Also, you cannot limit the width and the height of an image tag without distorting the image

Comment: Try using media queries to determine orientations: ` @media screen and (orientation:portrait) { … }
 @media screen and (orientation:landscape) { … }` and modify the width and height percentages accordingly.

Comment: Thank you guys, but I don't think it's possible to solve this. I tried flexbox, but it behaves the same: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sboesch/6yoLun5d/1/).
Media queries also won't work, because the image has an unknown aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Right, here's a solution (as best as i could tell from what you're trying to accomplish):

```
<div class='container'>
   <img class='image' src='http://placehold.it/1920x1080'>
</div>

body, .container{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow:hidden;
}
.container {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.image {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g33wLvhr/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this is not what I was looking for. I already know how to center a responsive image. My problem is an image inside a responsive container with position:relative. I think there doesn't exist any CSS-solution for this.